# How to find large web site favicons or logo from host link?

Tags: favicon

Is there a free solution to get the large logo or favicon (about 100 x 100 px) from a website from the host link?

I found several tracks but nothing satisfactory:

- Google S2 but I can not find a way to have a size larger than 32x32 or 64x64
  `http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain={URI.host}`
- In Google's Inbox, we find a "brand_avatar_url" which points to `https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/` where we can choose the size but the link can not be found as a simple user or even via the API

Do you know a simple and free solution?

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Asking for a recommendation of software is not allowed on SO.

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) :

> such icon files can be 16×16, 32×32, 48×48, or 64×64 pixels in size, and 8-bit, 24-bit, or 32-bit in color depth

And now [W3C](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon) :

> However, the format for the image you have chosen must be 16x16 pixels or 32x32 pixels, using either 8-bit or 24-bit colors. The format of the image must be one of PNG (a W3C standard), GIF, or ICO.

That's perfectly normal not to find a hi-res version of the favicon...

---

The favicon logo is usually hosted on the website itself, the simplest solution would be to look directly into the code :

```
<head>
    <title>Awesome Prods - Association de courts-métrages</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/icon/favicon.ico">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Awesome Prods, association de création de courts-métrages.">
</head>
```

The favicon is located in the `<link rel="icon">` tag.

Comment: I am looking for an automatic solution;)

Comment: That's why I specified favicon OR logo ;)